# Can you never have a dental cavity your entire life?

Tags: dentistry

I am 41 years old and I take terrible care of my teeth. I can remember when I was younger ,I never used to brush my teeth, maybe twice a week, nowadays if I remember I brush once a day. But still, maybe only 3-4 times a week. I don't mind the odd sugar snack as well. Always had white teeth even though I don't brush.

But despite all of this, I have **NEVER** had a cavity or even had pain in my gums or teeth area.

So can you go through your entire life without cavity?

Comment: Can you? Yes, obviously. I know quite a few people who do that. I’m quite the opposite of you - I brush regularly and even so I still get stains very easily. I don’t really see what you want though, TBH. Is a case example of someone who died without cavity proof enough? Maybe you can help me out understanding the core of your question...

Comment: As posed this is a yes or no question. Usually we like to give slightly longer answers. For that to happen you need to remove a little weakness of this question: Currently it is a bit unclear what you are asking. Please refine your question with the help of Narusan's comment and *the* [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: How do you know you've never had a cavity? Do you still go for regular 6 month dental cleanings and therefore have a record from the past ~30 years of never needing fillings?

Comment: @WakeDemons3, I go the dentist every couple of years.

Comment: @LangLangC, I am just looking for an answer the question??? Is this not a Q & A site to gather information? It is a very simple question, "Is it possible to never get a cavity in someone who lives to the average lifespan of a human?"

Comment: @LangLangC, as opposed to posting a question that will induce speculation? Is this not in line with the sites mantra?

Comment: This is such a Q&A site. My problem here is just to understand what this Q is about: it *is* phrased as a yes or no Q. That's a structural problem. And Narusan already gave an answer. If I'd suggest to add "How would that/ might be possible?" that would lead to speculation – or some solid statistics. – Perhaps simply: Try to rephrase it into a more open ended style? Help for that might be found [here] (https://health.stackexchange.com/help/asking). This is not lost, it needs a bit refining.

Comment: @LangLangC, I am lost as to how this should be reworded, but if you want to edit it to make it more compliant, I am not in objection.

Comment: @KyloRen - There is some opinion that "brushing" is harsher on Tooth Enamel and Gums and that we'd be better served by finger based scrubbing and gargling/ swishing with water / oil pulling etc. Did you practice any kind of post meal such activity? Do share more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could die today and that would make the answer yes.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-do-some-people-get-mo/

> Dental caries is the most prevalent infectious disease in humans,
>   affecting 97 percent of the population in their lifetime.

From the above we can conclude that 3% of the population go their entire lives without a cavity.